# RegEx to not much new line characters in Word

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have strings like this one:

> 7. Smith, John (1919-2006).
> 8. McKane, Vicky (1949-2012).

I would like to match

> `7.`   Smith, John `(1919-2006).`
>
> `8.`   McKane, Vicky `(1949-2012).`

I have came up with this `\s*[0-9]\.\s*|\s*(?:\([^()]*\))\.\s*` [link](https://regex101.com/r/vI1qI2/2). It does the trick, but it also catches new line characters which gives in MS Word the following string when regex is replaced with empty character `""` :

> Smith, JohmMcKane, Vicky

**EDIT:** Here is the VBA code I use:

```
With selection
        Dim RegEx As Object
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.MultiLine = True
        RegEx.Pattern = "\s*[0-9]\.\s*|\s*(?:\([^()]*\))\.\s*"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
End With
```

Comment: Why is your regex in an external link instead of in your question here where it is needed? Why should we have to leave this site to see what effort you've made? Please [edit] your question and put the relevant regex here, **in text form**, where it can be seen or copy/pasted for testing if needed. We should not have to go elsewhere to find the relevant information.

Comment: Please post the VBA code you are using. Note that `\s` can be safely replaced with `[ \t]` to only match ASCII regular horizontal whitespace. Try `[ \t]*[0-9]\.[ \t]*|[ \t]*(?:\([^()]*\))\.[ \t]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my post. Your regex does the trick, however, one new line (unnecessary) is added when the VBA code is run.

Comment: Is that newline critical? Shall I post or look for a way to get rid of it?

Comment: It seems that the last linebreak is only added if you select the whole text. If you do not select the last paragraph break symbol, and run the regex replacement, it will replace OK.

Comment: This line is not critical. If you have some free time, please look into this. If not, I will run replace again to remove this empty line. Regardless of your choice, I think your regex deserves to be marked as an 'answer'.

Comment: I managed to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it a lot, and the best I could achieve is

```
[ \t]*[0-9]\.[ \t]*|[ \t]*(?:\([^()]*\))\.[ \t]*
```

Or - since you have the Multiline option on:

```
^[ \t]*[0-9]\.[ \t]*|[ \t]*(?:\([^()" & vbCr & vbLf & "]*\))\.[ \t]*$
```

Both will result in

```
Smith, John
McKane, Vicky
```

Note that `\s` can be safely replaced with `[ \t]` to only match ASCII regular horizontal whitespace.

The last paragraph separator is added by all means *only if the whole contents are selected before the replacement*. If you select all but the last separator, the additional separator won't be inserted.

So, you may use this workaround:

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Select
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
With Selection
        Dim RegEx As Object
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.MultiLine = True
        RegEx.Pattern = "^[ \t]*[0-9]\.[ \t]*|[ \t]*(?:\([^()" & vbCr & vbLf & "]*\))\.[ \t]*$"
        .Text = RegEx.Replace(.Text, "")
End With
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> [^\S\n]

Will match any whitespace that isn't a new line

```
/\s*[0-9]\.\s*|\s*(?:\([^()]*\))\.[^\S\n]*/g
```

However, I would suggest an alternative way to do what you are trying to do.

```
/\d\.\s(.*)\s\(.*\)\./g
```

Will match the lines you've asked, but put the names into a Capture Group for easy retrieval later.

Comment: `\s*[0-9]\.\s*|\s*(?:\([^()]*\))\.[^\S\n]*` used in Word gives the same result as my code. [/\d\.\s(.*)\s\(.*\)\./g](https://regex101.com/r/vI1qI2/3) work great at https://regex101.com but in Word it almost removes everything. Can you check the code in Word, please?